# How to run php code after facebook javascript sdk is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm developing a facebook application using php sdk and trying to get Access Tokens from the JavaScript SDK. But the problem is javascript SDK take time in loading and my php code run before javascript SDK is fully loaded thats why i cant get the Access Token.
This is my code.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
  appId   : '{app-id}',
  cookie  : true,
  version : 'v2.4'
});
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


</script>
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '............',
  'app_secret' => '..................',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

if(!isset($_SESSION["AccessToken"])) {

$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

if(isset($accessToken)) {
$_SESSION["AccessToken"]= (string)$accessToken;
}
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'AccessGraph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

 session_destroy();
 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  session_destroy();
 exit;
}
}

echo $_SESSION["AccessToken"];

?>
```

If i reload the page the code work properly and i successfully get the Access Token because JavaScript SDK is already loaded. 
Please tell me how i resolve this?

Comment: Which `login` method you are using ? JS or PHP ? Why are you mixing things ?

Answer (score 2):

Normally your php file will be executed and the result gets displayed by the browser.

This means your **php code will run before any of the javascript generated** by your script is even delivered to the browser for execution.

If you really have to run the php code after the js code then you should use javascript to load the php code right after all neccessary libraries of your js haven been loaded.

Using jquery this can be done like this.

```
<div id="success"></div>
<div id="error"></div>

<script>
  $( "#success" ).load( "/my-file.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Error occured while loading my script: ";
    $("#error").html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
</script>
```

This woul load `my-file.php`, display it's output in `div#success` and give you an error message in `div#error` if anything goes wrong.

Comment: _Normally_  ? What is the other case when it will not ?

Comment: There is no other case as long as the javascript is generated by the very same php file.

Comment: I found the solution just use your JavaScript in head section of your page then it will load before your php code.